# Several entityManager at runtime in webapp

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my web application, when a new user sign-up i need to create a new database in mysql for him. Example: root => db_root, admin => db_admin, user1 => db_user1 and so on. When the user logs into my app, I need to instance a new entityManager based on his new created database and manipulate data only on that db.

One problem is: how am i supposed to know which entityManager instance i should use for each user request. I thought about creating a

`Hashmap<String, EntityManager>`

save an attribute entityManagerKey on user's session and retrieve the right entityManager by this key. This approach brings along some troubles such as the right time to destroy a non-used entityManager. Moreover, i think it will take all server memory to work.

Though it's seems to be not a great idea, i did't realize another solution. I'm using JPA/Hibernate and Jersey. Any ideas will be appreciated, except creating only one database.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have to create a new database per user? I've never seen a use case requiring it.

Comment: mszymborski, it's really weird. Although it's not necessary, my client demmanded it and i failed to convince him to not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EntityManagerFactory and pass it the user and password

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "admin");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "admin");
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
   "some-jdbc-url", properties);
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

If you think performance is an issue, you can cache the entityManager. Depending on how much traffic you have on your application and the available resources, you can determine the number of cached connections. I wouldn't bother with caching in the beginning, because creating a DB connection is usually not that time consuming, compared to a web request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code,

```
 private static final Map<String, EntityManagerFactory> ENTITY_FACTORIES = new HashMap<String, EntityManagerFactory>();

    public void onStart() {
            this.buildEntityManagerFactories();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            closeEMFactories();
        }

        private void closeEMFactories() {
            try {
                if(ENTITY_FACTORIES.size() > 0) {
                    for(Entry<String, EntityManagerFactory> entityFactoryMgr : ENTITY_FACTORIES.entrySet()) {
                        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = entityFactoryMgr.getValue();
                        if(entityManagerFactory.isOpen()) {
                            entityManagerFactory.close();
                        }
                    }
                    isLoaded = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.error("Error while shutting down the datasource plugin", e);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Create the entityManagerFactory Bean.
         * @return entityManagerFactory Bean
         */
        public void buildEntityManagerFactories(String userName) {
            buildEMFactory(userName, DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
        }

        private void buildEMFactory(String userName, String persistenceUnitName) {
            if(!isLoaded) {
                try{
                    ENTITY_FACTORIES.put(userName, Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, XOAPP_DB_PROPERTIES));
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    Logger.error("Error while building the entity manager factory for the persistence unit :" + persistenceUnitName, e);
                }
            }
        }

        public EntityManager em(String persistenceName) {
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = ENTITY_FACTORIES.get(persistenceName);
            if(entityManagerFactory != null) {
                return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            }
            return null;
        }

/**
         * Get the entityManagerFactory Bean.
         * @return entityManagerFactory Bean
         */
        public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(String userName) {
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = ENTITY_FACTORIES.get(userName);
            if(entityManagerFactory == null) {
                buildEMFactory(userName);
                entityManagerFactory = ENTITY_FACTORIES.get(userName);
            }
            return entityManagerFactory;
        }
```